Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql
I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database with SQLAlchemy. I followed the FastAPI tutorial, and I had an old URL, which looks just like postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}, and it worked. However, I deleted postgresql and pgAdmin from my computer for some stupid reason. By the time I re-installed them, the URL didn't work anymore...
This is my code:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from .Config import settings

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
    settings.database_username, 
    settings.database_password, 
    settings.database_hostname, 
    settings.database_port, 
    settings.database_name
    )

This is what I am getting:
   File "/Users/temp_user_name/Desktop/project/application/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .Database import *
  File "/Users/temp_user_name/Desktop/project/application/Database.py", line 14, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/Users/temp_user_name/Desktop/project/virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/temp_user_name/Desktop/project/virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 552, in create_engine
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/temp_user_name/Desktop/project/virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 754, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/temp_user_name/Desktop/project/virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 367, in load
    raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql


That's very strange- it seems it can't find the built-in postgresql dialect. Have you tried re-installing SQLAlchemy?  Note that you will also need to install psycopg2, but as far as I can tell you would get a different error message if the problem was psycopg2 being missing.

Apparently, they are already installed.                                          Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in ./virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.0.21) Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.2.0 in ./virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from sqlalchemy) (4.7.1) Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in ./virtual/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from sqlalchemy) (2.0.2)

Does this problem have to do with the version of sqlalchemy, Postgresql or pgAdmin? Nothing else in my project changed.

Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling or just force installing sqlalchemy psycopg.  Sometimes there is a C extension that is compiled for the postgresql driver and maybe it got messed up.

Specific in this case if you had one version of postgresql installed and then uninstalled it and then reinstalled a new version that would cause an issue with the python driver.

Thanks everybody! now it works. @IanWilson, I uninstalled and reinstalled SQLalchemy.

@IanWilson, as you mentioned, an issue would occur with the python driver. Would reinstalling SQLalchemy completely solve the problem? Or could there still be conflicts?

I'm not 100% sure, you only re-installed sqlalchemy?  You didn't reinstall psycopg?

No, I didn't reinstall psycopg.
